# Select files on Android web with input type=file: excel files incorrectly available to select, and return PDF mime type

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, mime-types, input-type-file

I want to limit file uploads on my mobile web app to image and PDF file types. However, when I open the file picker in Chrome on Android, I can select excel files, which should not be available to select based on what I've specified in the [accept attribute of the input element](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/accept-type-attribute/). The problem seems to be specific to Android- excel files are grayed out in iOS and are hidden on desktop.

Furthermore, if I navigate to Google Drive through the file picker and select an excel file, the returned mime type of the file is `application/pdf`. Here, I would expect  `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` or `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` as the mime type. This only happens for excel files from Google Drive i.e. selecting an excel file from Downloads returns the expected mime type.

Therefore, I have two questions:

**1. Is it expected behavior for Android to not adhere to file types specified in the accept attribute?**

**2. Why are excel files selected from Google Drive returned with PDF mime type?**

Input element that accepts image and PDF files:

```
<input onchange="showImage('Files')" type="file" name="Files" accept="image/*,.pdf" value="Upload a file"">
```

Function that triggers after I select the [excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjJJl.png):

```
function showImage(type){
  var file = document.querySelector(`input[name=${type}]`).files[0];
  console.log(file);
}
```

And the log of the selected file:

`File(47847) {name: "Gratefulness.pdf", lastModified: 1536163728724, lastModifiedDate: Wed Sep 05 2018 11:08:49 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 47847, …}
lastModified: 1536163745655
lastModifiedDate: Wed Sep 05 2018 11:09:06 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central) {}
name: "Gratefulness.pdf"
size: 47847
type: "application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File`